# Error limit size post Json Android export .NET

Tags: android, .net, json, size, image-size

I'm working with an export of data, including images in an Android application to Web application generated .Net.

I'm thinking that the error is in the amount of information generated by JSON, such as sending information with 3 images is correct, when you put 4 or plus pictures, the error occurs in post shipping.

Need some help, or another type of solution like sending separate images.

tks

Comment: The maximum limit is theoretically unlimited. IIS has a setting in the configuration to increase it, by default it's 2mb I think for iis6 and increased in later versions. A better solution might be to send each file separately so you can better avoid reaching any limit. Some routers are also configured to reset httpconnections after say 5 mins active, so again you'd be avoiding that issue too.

Comment: Do you generate Base64 string from images?
In any cases I don`t think that is optimal approach. Maybe you should upload images to some server and than put links in your JSON?
If my assumption is not correct - give some additional info.

Comment: Yes generate base64 images. This solution sending via ftp is a good idea! 

I will implement this alternative. 

tks

Comment: No problem. But you owe me a beer;)

Comment: Json is not a wrong approach, that's what bson is for.  Standing up another ftpserver is going to add complexity to the mix when you could just keep it contained.